# mageplaza social login LinekdIn error

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

For some reason when I try to use the MagePlaza Social Login extension, LinkedIn login throws this error:
[image]
[image]
my configuration  and ID on LinkedIn
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Could you show which config u use ???

Comment: Please update you question by using `edit` link located below your question, you posted an answer which is wrong...

Comment: I added my configuration and id on Linkedin

Answer (score 0):

1. Okay, If your config looks like this, right?

```
$config = array(
  "base_url" => "http://mywebsite.com/path/to/hybridauth",
  "providers" => array(
    "LinkedIn"  => array(
      "enabled" => true,
      "keys"    => array("id" => "YOUR_CLIENT_ID", "secret" => "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"),
      "scope"   => array("r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress"),
    ),
  ),
)
```

2. and `here https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/auth` you have checked these scopes?
   [image]
3. and here `https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/auth` you have something like this?
   [image]

Please verify all 3 steps.